# Using Store + Zoo Visitor to create a member and store order details in related entry

Tags: expresso-store, zoo-visitor

We have one checkout at the moment that requires a customer to sign up at the checkout (this creates a member record with ZV) and once signed up/in they can purchase their course which will then create an entry in our 'Students' channel. Simple.

What we need now is for someone to be able to handle 'manual' registrations and therefore need to be able to sign up and purchase in the same step on behalf of the student.

I am able to register a member with Store, however, because the member wasn't created prior to the order the entry is not created in our 'Students' channel.
Has anyone had any experience with this? or any ideas that would help point us in the right direction.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What version if Store, ZooVisitor and EE are you using?

Comment: Store: 1.6.3
ZooVisitor: 1.3.21
EE: 2.5.5

Comment: We might need to pull the Zoo team in on this. Store just registers the member in EE, but Zoo probably doesn't create the related entry unless you use their registration tags.

Comment: @AdrianMacneil what exactly does that involve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a flowchart to visualize the implementation

Basically it comes down to these steps:

1. Add product to cart (Store)
2. Cart overview - proceed to checkout (Store)
3. New vs. returning customer / Login - Registration form (Visitor)
4. Final checkout, here you will pass the visitor member data into hidden store checkout fields
5. Done :)

[image: Visitor-Store implementation flowchart]

Comment: Thanks so much for the steps and the flowchart. I figured that they must be a member before the entry will be created because no-one had mentioned anything different. Again, many thanks