# Expresso Store & Zoo Visitors are they playing together during checkout?

Tags: expresso-store, zoo-visitor

I know there are already some questions about this but I need some feedback with the latest configuration of both.

So the latest versions are:

- EE 2.9.3 (I let 2.10 to the more brave out there)
- Expresso Store **2.5.0**
- Zoo Visitor **1.3.32**

**The Question**

Is it possible to register a zoo visitor member during Store checkout?

**What I did:**

1) create all Expresso Store Order fields as native EE member custom fields (e.g. created "billing_first_name" as a native member custom field etc etc.)

2) Delete all default Zoo Visitor fields except the first one (member_account) and recreate all fields but **using "member_" prefix to get automatic sync**.
(e.g. created "member_billing_first_name")

3) In Store > Settings > Order Fields MAPPED all fields to Zoo Visitor custom fields

4) register_member="yes" to the exp:store:checkout

5) Added {field:password} and {field:password_confirm} to checkout

**What Happens?**

1) I'm able to complete order but I only get a native member WITHOUT any custom field populated...
2) Also receive the "Member Account Activation Instructions" native email

Thanks
Francesco

**EDIT:**

want to reference this workaround (that I haven't tried yet) just to ask if it is still actual:
https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zoo-visitor/viewthread/14068

Or maybe this is the only way?
[Using Store + Zoo Visitor to create a member and store order details in related entry](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9633/using-store-zoo-visitor-to-create-a-member-and-store-order-details-in-related/9679#9679)

Answer (score 1):

I've read through your links in your edit and they seem relivent still. Your first link evolves into the second link anyway, but the method described (make sure you work through the whole thread) looks ok to me. The only thing I would do is avoid the optional membership thing on the store if you possibly can.

Also, see here (Is alomost a duplicate of your post), This post goes into the field mappings a bit more. : [Expresso Store 2: not mapping to Zoo Visitors fields on checkout](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14342/expresso-store-2-not-mapping-to-zoo-visitors-fields-on-checkout) (and remember to call `{exp:zoo_visitor:sync}` on success to push the data to the Zoo Visitor Channel.

See also :

- https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/zoo-visitor/viewthread/7757
- [Zoo Visitor change log, confirms Store support in 2.1.0](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html)